# Use a char array in a std::string in C++11

Tags: c++11, malloc, stdstring

I'm not sure if this is safe, what will happen when the string gets out of scope?:

```
std::string tmp_str( strdup("wlan0"));
```

I know that strdup uses malloc to allocate new space for the string which will be used by tmp_string.

I'm not interested in a solution, I would like to know if there will be any issue using strdup.

Comment: It will leak memory. Why do you need strdup?

Answer (score 4):

The `std::string` class copies *the string*, not the pointer to the string. That means that the memory allocated by `strdup` will be lost forever for your process.

There's simply no need to use `strdup` in that way. And besides that, string literals will exist for the life-time of the program, so pointers to them will never become invalid.